# Unable to print usernames longer than 8 chars with "w" in linux

Tags: linux

I am doing a linux script to extract which users are logged onto a machine, from where, and how long they have been idle.
So far I have been using the "w" command in linux.
However I now noticed that it truncates usernames and source

I have three users logged on
testuser
testuser-new
lala-testuser

They are logged on from either: testserver, or superdupertestserver

The output of w is:

```
testuser   pts/2    testserver       10:12   29.00s  0.15s  0.15s -bash
testuser   pts/3    superdupertestse 10:12   21.00s  0.18s  0.18s -bash
lala-tes   pts/4    superdupertestse 10:12   21.00s  0.18s  0.18s -bash
```

I am already using "long listing" of the output. Is there a way to fix this, or do get the information from the source w is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man w:

```
ENVIRONMENT
       PROCPS_USERLEN
              Override  the default width of the username column.  Defaults to
              8.

       PROCPS_FROMLEN
              Override the default width of the from column.  Defaults to 16.
```

Comment: Can you point me to the right man page? I just have this: https://linux.die.net/man/1/w

Comment: Which version of `w` are you using?

Comment: `$ w --version
w from procps-ng 3.3.12`

Comment: Hmm. I have `3.3.10`. Looks like the feature is hidden in that version. It works but it is not documented in the man page.

Comment: You're using a distro made by lazy developers, who skipped updating manpages.

Comment: I am running w version 3.2.7 on which the environmental variables have not  been added yet it seems. I can confirm it works on w version 3.3.10

Comment: @IporSircer I just checked Gentoo and they have it in the man page ;)

Comment: Confirmed not working with `procps version 3.2.7` on RHEL5.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @hek2mgl: you just need to **export** the variable:

```
patrick_westwood@james:~$ export PROCPS_USERLEN=20

patrick_westwood@james:~$ w

 17:53:10 up 1 day, 18 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

USER                 TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT

patrick_westwood     pts/0    174.1.33.169     16:54    6.00s  0.19s  0.00s w

patrick_westwood     pts/1    174.1.33.169     16:54   58:41   0.00s  0.00s -bash
```

Answer (score 1):

`w` gets the information from `/var/run/utmp`. If your version of `w` does not support the `PROCPS_USERLEN` environment variable you can use the `utmpdump` command and parse it with `awk`:

The following command for example would extract the usernames:

```
utmpdump /var/run/utmp | awk '{gsub(/[][]/, "", $4); print $4}'
```

Comment: Sure, but it also uses it's own output format which may be desired or not. `utmpdump` is the most flexible solution at the end.

Comment: The data I wanted to extract from w was username, tty, idle time and from. Seems I need to use w to get the idle time, and then get the rest of the data from last or utmpdump